# Función nativa de Php para mover el puntero en mi funcion

Tags: php, symfony

Hola tengo la siguiente duda. Tengo una función en la que compruebo si existe el año y después compruebo si existe el mes. Cuando no existe el año lo crea porque entra en el else pero esto hace que el script continue sin poder validar el mes.
Se que Php tiene un método nativo en el que puedes mover el puntero de ejecución llamando a un método donde quieres que se ponga el puntero. EJEMPLO:

```
//Comprueba si existe la carpeta del año
if($fileSystem->exists($dir_year)){
    $a;  //Saltaría a esta linea y seguiria hacia abajo.

    //Comprueba si existe la carpeta del mes
    if($fileSystem->exists($dir_month)){

    }else{
           //Creo el mes
           $fileSystem->mkdir($dir_month, 0700);
    }
}else{
    //Creo el año
    $fileSystem->mkdir($dir_year, 0700);
    pointer($a); //Me lo e inventado porque no se como se llama el metodo
}
```

> Con esto evitaria hacer un loop o hacer una funcion personalizada solo
>   para esta tarea.

Comment: No te hace falta complicarlo tanto, simplemente saca el if del mes fuera del primero.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *puntero*? Si explicas mejor el contexto quizá se te podría sugerir una solución adecuada. ¿Estás leyendo un archivo, datos de una base de datos,  o que es?

Comment: $dir_year contiene el path donde se encuentra la carpeta año.$dir_month contiene el path donde se encuentra la carpeta mes. $fileSystem es una clase de Symfony para administrar ficheros

Comment: Quizá debiste mencionar `Symfony` e incluso ponerle la etiqueta a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de filesystem: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#mkdir

Te crea el directorio de forma recursiva.

Por lo tanto, creo que simplemente debes chequear si el directorio compuesto $año$mes No existe. En ese caso, crea el directorio con mkdir.

```
 If(!$filename->exista($dir_year$dir_month)) {
$filesystem->mkdir($dir_year$dir_month); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar saltos ([`goto`](http://php.net/control-structures.goto)) es una técnica poco recomendada y muy propensa a generar errores difícilmente depurables (y posiblemente bucles infinitos). Sólo hay que mirar [la tira cómica](https://xkcd.com/292/) que tienen en el manual de PHP.

Para solucionar tu problema basta con hacer las comprobaciones de manera secuencial y no anidada:

```
//Comprueba si existe la carpeta del año
if ($fileSystem->exists($dir_year) == false) {
    //Creo el año
    $fileSystem->mkdir($dir_year, 0700);
}
//Comprueba si existe la carpeta del mes
if($fileSystem->exists($dir_month) == false){
    //Creo el mes
    $fileSystem->mkdir($dir_month, 0700);
}
```

De esta manera si no existe el directorio del año, lo creará. Luego comprobará si existe el subdirectorio del mes y si no existe (hubiera creado o no recientemente el directorio del año) también lo creará.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré como se hace, al parecer se llama goto. Implementado desde la version 5.3.0 hasta la actual.

http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.goto.php

Esto salta a otra sección del programa.
Con esto te ahorras tener que hacer un bucle y hacer comprobaciones laboriosas. Si estas seguro que quieres un flujo de datos elegante y sencillo creo que esta es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Ademas si anidas varios bucles haces que sea mas eficiente la salida de todos los bucles porque no necesitas hacer **break;** en cada uno de ellos y evitando cálculos innecesarios.

EJEMPLO:

```
<?php
   goto a;
   echo 'Foo';

   a:
   echo 'Bar';
?>
```

Esto mostraría **Bar**.

Se puede hacer tanto hacia arriba como hacia abajo.

> Solo lo puedes usar dentro del mismo contexto, no puedes saltar de función en función, solo en el mismo bloque.

Comment: Supongo que ya lo sabes, pero no es bueno el uso de foto en esta estructura. Es mejor que no lo uses y cambies la lógica de tu codigo

Comment: @Jakala ¿el uso de `foto` no es bueno? :)

Comment: Escribi esto desde la tablet y me lo cambio por foto No es recomendable porque puede llegar a complicar el algoritmo que diseñas con goto. Existen técnicas (como el backtracking) que se basaban en el para recorrer el arbol de  decisiones (como el laberinto) pero estos algoritmos se pueden simplificar con try/catch